# Spraying aluminium hydroxide nanoparticles onto PLA as fire retardant?

Tags: pla

Several scientific papers study FR-PLA (fire resistant PLA) in which Aluminium Hydroxide nanoparticles are melt blended into the PLA (example source: [Advances in Flame Retardant Poly(Lactic Acid)](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/326872529_Advances_in_Flame_Retardant_PolyLactic_Acid). Would spraying the nanoparticles (dispersed in a liquid -[source](https://www.us-nano.com/inc/sdetail/1094) - maybe non flammable silicon oil) onto a 3D printed PLA help with fire resistance or not make a difference?

Comment: Why would spraying water help? It's not going to infuse the particles into the plastic. At best it would make an extremely thin useless layer.

Comment: We could disperse the particles in another liquid than water: https://www.us-nano.com/inc/sdetail/1094 Which liquid would stick onto PLA? Silicon oil maybe?

Comment: It has to be inside the pla. This is more a question for a material science Q&A site.

Comment: @user77232 i have transferred the question to the physics Stack Exchange as well: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/466676/spraying-aluminium-hydroxide-nanoparticles-onto-pla-as-fire-retardant

Comment: That... is Material sciene and chemistry, not physics and not here...

Comment: BTW,  "Fire Retardant" is **not** "FireProof" .  See the expose articles on cigarette smoking, fire-retardant furniture and bedding.  So long as there's an exposed heat source, fire-retardant material will continue to burn.  So the whole concept re PLA is pretty much pointless.